# How can I change the "licensed to" in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm not sure how it happened, but on startup my VS 2012 copy reads

```
Licensed To: "----------------Hewlet-Packard (blah)..."
```

I have no idea how that got there. We installed through our MSDN subscription. Anyone know of a simple way to replace this with either my name or my company's?

This makes me sad inside.

Comment: This is a software user question, not a programming question (even though it's VS-2012 related). It doesn't belong here. Voting to close (and you should probably delete), but you can find the information it reads in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, as `RegisteredOrganization` and `RegisteredOwner`. Windows Installer reads the information from there, and usually presents it to you to change during the install process. Note that the information in this key is **global**, meaning changes can affect other things on your system.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For Windows 7 I found the following instructions on [this site](http://blog.brouwer.pro/2012/09/how-to-change-licensed-to-name-for-visual-studio-2012/):

> 1. Open Registry Editor (Start->Run->type “regedit”->press enter)
> 2. Find the following key:
>      `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Registration\UserName`
> 3. Change it’s value to the desired name
> 4. Navigate to the following folder:
>      `C:\Users\{YOUR_USER}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0`
>      (replace the placeholder with your own username)
> 5. Delete the file `vs000223.dat` – this is actually a JPG file
>      containing the splash screen, you can change it’s name to see it for
>      yourself
> 6. Start Visual Studio, and it magically recreates the file with the
>      modified name in it!

Comment: The path to vs000223.dat in my case was C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\

Comment: To expand a bit on wizlb's comment, I'm running Windows 7 SP1 on a 64-bit machine and mine was in that location as well. Regedit changes are only necessary to change the name; search for RegisteredOrganization key to change the company.

Comment: For those using **VS Express** - substitute `VisualStudio` to `WDExpress` or `VWDExpress` depending on which edition you are using. Process `regedit` then `AppData` and `ProgramData` still applies.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you have to delete the vs000223.dat from both ProgramData and AppData. The one in AppData acts as the main Splash Screen while the one in ProgramData acts as a backup. If the one in AppData does not exist, Visual Studio 'copies' the one from ProgramData. If both don't exist, Visual Studio writes a new vs000223.dat into AppData but not into ProgramData.