# How can I change the "licensed to" in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I followed the steps in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/498295/how-can-i-change-the-licensed-to-in-visual-studio). The registry location was different, and in fact didn't contain "Hewlett-Packard". I searched and replaced this in the registry (RegisteredOrganization, Company, CompanyName, RegCompany keys where applicable), and I deleted the dat file, but the splash screen still displays the incorrect data.

However, Help -> About... displays the correct data.

How do I get the splash screen updated?

I'm running Win 8.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstalled the product?  Normally when I install VS2012 I am given a chance to say who its registered to.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's another day's worth of downloads, so I'm avoiding that option.

Comment: I would try that before you dismiss the option.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause seem to be that the OS itself is registered to HP. Pre-installed machine? This will fix the about dialog:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4248ffc5-14ff-4b6d-a74b-460218bcf7c3/hp-hijacked-my-visual-studio-registration?forum=vssetup

To update the splash screen delete:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\vs000223.dat

Comment: OP said: "However, Help -> About... displays the correct data.", and "I deleted the dat file, but the splash screen still displays the incorrect data", so your answer is suggesting doing what he says he already tried (based on the question he linked) and it didn't work.  Also, please don't just post bare links, instead include pertinent information directly in your answer(s).

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the question right. I encountered this problem. The linked solution didn't help me. However MS link above helped to get the about box right as my machine was 64 bit. Then I searched the machine for vs00*.dat and found it in a different folder. I did all this while VS was closed.

Comment: I can't recall now how I resolved this, but I did.