# Are there any practical issues with choosing a username other than my real name on Windows?

Tags: user-accounts, windows-8.1, username

As a new laptop (running Windows 8.1 Pro) is going to be delivered to me soon, I'm thinking about choosing a username different than just my first and last name. However, I'm concerned that the username may be used by software in contexts where something other than my real name would not be appropriate.

Where can I expect my username to be used in software, and are there going to be any serious practical issues if I don't use my real name for my user account?

Comment: Microsoft unlike Google does not require your actual name to create a Microsoft account.  Of course a fake name makes purchasing anything nearly impossible for logical reasons

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not talking about the Microsoft account. I'm talking about the local account name.

Comment: Does it not depend on the software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your username in Windows is just for Windows. Nearly all software will allow you to customize. Some prominent software, such as Microsoft Office products, pull your Windows username into the software by default; however, they offer a simple way to change that within the software option menu.

So the bottom line is that you shouldn't worry, choose whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Visual Studio is a more concerning case: http://superuser.com/questions/498295/how-can-i-change-the-licensed-to-in-visual-studio

Comment: It does seem that you can change it manually afterwards using those instructions though, so I'd still stick with my desired username.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can see the username that someone would use for windows 8.1 has no effect except for things that deliberately say sign in with Microsoft account and are even apps bought from the windows store (I.e Skype) but these are little in numbers as far as i can see.